# Do we have orange runway markings?

Tags: airport-markings, parallel-runways, rules-of-the-air, japan

[image]

As you can see in this picture, the runway markings are in orange or yellow.

Comment: what country are you asking about?

Comment: I am confused by your question. The answer seems to be pretty clear: since there exists a photograph of orange runway markings, it is clear that we have orange runway markings. Or are you asking whether the photo is fake? That does not sound like an Aviation question to me.

Comment: In our country rules (Iran) we have only white markings for runway. Also I checked FAA and I understood that FAA rules as like as ours. https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/aim_html/chap2_section_3.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

White runway markings that turn orange are affected by a contaminant in the aggregate of the asphalt.  There are modifications that can be made to the paint to resist the rust-staining.  A study by the New Hampshire Department of Transportation studied several paint formulas and had the greatest success with a stain-resistant paint formula manufactured by Safety Coatings of Foley, AL.  FHWA-NH-RD-26962T

Answer (score 10):

> Do we have orange runway markings?

Yes. We do, apparently.

Longer answer:

I didn't expect aviation.stackexchange would be similar to geoguessr, but this appears to be [New Chitose Airport in Japan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Chitose_Airport). The following Google Satellite view is approximately what can be seen in the photo:

[image: Google satellite view of New Chitose Airport, Japan]

It can also be seen [in this Wikimedia Commons photo](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:New_Chitose_airport_from_the_sky.JPG). [Per a discussion on airliners.net](https://www.airliners.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=774769), "in Japan they do have yellow/orange runway markings, but only in areas which get lot of snow... It seems that the use of orange markings only applies to civilian airports, as military bases seem to use white markings. For example in New Chitose Airport / Chitose Air Base, the civilian side has orange markings, and the military side uses white ones."

Comment: Thanks for your help. I checked my country rules and also FAA and just find white markings for runways as I expected. Btw, so is this only for Japan?

Comment: [Norway does as well](https://www.airliners.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=412917), rationale is that it's easier to see when there is snow on the runway. [They have changed from yellow to white in the last 10 years](https://forums.x-plane.org/index.php?/forums/topic/126674-norwegian-yellow-runway-markings/).

Comment: Using Google Earth, I can see Norway's ENGM changed from yellow to white between 2015-2018. More unique: Thule Air Base's entire runway was painted white ~1960 to decrease permafrost melting. It had red markings until ~2012.

Comment: Thank you sir..